# How to fix, TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that calculates the grades, calculates the average, and shows a error when letters are typed in. I think I am pretty much done with the code, but I am confused on how to fix "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" problem.

```
def calculate_average(total, count):
    average = total / count
    return average

while 1:
    try:
        grade = float(input("Enter a test score, or a negative number to get the average: "))
        total = sum(grade)
        count = len(grade)
        if grade < 0:
            break
        average = calculate_average(total, count)
        print("Total: ", total)
        print("Average:", round(average))
    except ValueError:
        print("BRUH")
```

Comment: `total = sum(grade)`? That's not how this works, that's not how any of this works!

Comment: `grade` is a single grade, not a list of grades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you want to user to input multiple numbers. However, in your code the user can only enter a single number and a single foat can obviously not be summed up nor has it a length.

You need a list containing all grades and after the user has entered all grades and entered a negative number you can evaluate that list and calculate the average.

Here is a working example:

```
def calculate_average(total, count):
    average = total / count
    return average

while 1:
        grades = []
        while 1:
            inp = input("Enter a test score, or a negative number to get the average: ")

            try:
                inpGrade = float(inp)

                if inpGrade > 0:
                    grades.append(inpGrade)
                elif inpGrade < 0:
                    break

            except ValueError:
                print("BRUH")

        total = sum(grades)
        count = len(grades)
        average = calculate_average(total, count)
        print("Total: ", total)
        print("Average:", round(average))
        break
```